# Specific matrix has no 2-dimensional invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence, invariance

I have the endomorphism
$$ M =  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$
of a real vector space $V$. Note that this matrix is nilpotent (with $M^3 = 0$), not diagonalizable, and not invertible.

Basically, I need to show that this matrix does not have an infinite amount of invariant subspaces $U$. If $\dim U = 0$ or $\dim U = 3$, then we have the trivial invariant subspaces, but that's just 2 subspaces.

If $\dim U = 1$, then we have the following. If the basis of $U$ is the vector $(r, s, t) \neq \textbf{0}$, then we have $M \cdot (r, s, t) = (s, t, 0) \in U$, so $(s, t, 0) = \lambda (r, s, t) = (\lambda r, \lambda s, \lambda t) $ for some $\lambda \in R$. But then either $\lambda = 0$ or $t = 0$. The former (or both at the same time) would give us $s = t = 0$, so then $U$ would be the $x$-axis (so now we have 3 subspaces), and the latter would give a contradiction, since we now have $\lambda \neq 0$ and then we would have $r = s = t = 0$, contradicting the fact that $(r, s, t) \neq \textbf{0}$. [The reason we could say that $\lambda \neq 0$ is because we already handled the case of both $\lambda = 0$ *and* $t = 0$.]

But what about $\dim U = 2$? Does $M$ even have invariant subspaces of dimension 2? If so, how can we show that there is only a finite amount of them?

Comment: The image of $M$ is 2-dimensional. Obviously it is the only 2-dimensional space that $M$ can leave invariant. So all you need to do is determine whether that one plane is invariant under $M$.

Comment: Wonderful! Of course, since rk $M = 2$, if a 2-dimensional subspace is $M$-invariant, it must be a subspace of the image of $M$. Thus, it is either the image of $M$ itself or some lower-dimensional subspace, but we already handled the 1- and 0-dimensional case. In all cases: a finite amount of invariant subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $P$ be an $M$-invariant plane. Note that $x\in P$ iff $x^Tu=u^Tx=0$. Here $x\in P$ implies $Mx\in P$, that is $x^Tu=0$ implies $u^TMx=x^T(M^Tu)=0$. Thus $u$ is an eigenvector of $M^T$; up to a factor, $u=[0,0,1]^T$ and the sole solution is the plane $x_3=0$.
2. A matrix $M\in M_n(K)$ admits a finite number of invariant subspaces iff $M$ is cyclic, that is, iff its minimal polynomial has degree $n$. Here the minimal polynomial of $M$ is $x^3$.

Comment: I'm assuming that $u$ is the normal vector. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes $u$ is A normal vector.